# Include does nothing

Tags: php, include, require

I want to chceck files before I'll connect domain on my server. I've added them in direct admin, I've uploaded files - but I don't know how to get to them.

I have 4 domains connected, but i have acces only to one. I saw that it's possible to include file from higher level

```
include('../../panele-podlogowe.eu/adm/img/edit.gif')
```

That gave me correct image. But when I've done:

```
include('../../panele-podlogowe.eu/index.php');
```

Nothing happens (I've turned Error reporting on).

When I did something like:

```
include('../../panele-podlogowe.eu/index.php');
echo 'Failed?';
```

Nothing prints out... What the heck?

Solution:

```
 ini_set("display_errors", "stdout");
```

Comment: What is your error reporting level?

Comment: In which file did you turn on error reporting?

Comment: Check your error reporting level and see the ini directrives log_errors and display_errors. See http://pt.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors http://pt.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors http://pt.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

Comment: try to require the file, as opposed to include that will cause it to issue a fatal as opposed to a warning.  Also look at the contents of the index.php file,  is it including other files/resources?

Comment: @Gumbo - E_ALL
@BoltClock - in both files, at the beginning
@Artefacto - thanks! It looks like errors are saved to file... How can i change that?
@Doon - require same - yup, the index.php is some kind of loader so it doesn't print content itself

Comment: I'm I the only one to be shocked to see an image as parameter of `include()` ?

Comment: @misiur are you just trying to get the output of the index.php to show on a different page, or are you trying to include all the loader stuff to be able to use it below?

Comment: @Doon - I'm trying to include all the loader stuff - because as I said i need to chceck whole system, but I can't do it normally, while I don't have domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the PHP error log. That usually, even under default settings, shows what's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Enable error reporting so php will print what is wrong. Add this at the top of your file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Otherwise:

- Check the access permissions for that file
- Double-check the file you are including for syntax errors. (if the include causes php to crash/segfault you might not get any output)