# After php 5.5 update include () no longer works

Tags: php, html, include

I am trying to install an opensource php CRM and it required I update my php version.  Switched to 5.5 and now my include doesn't work.

I have tried:

```
include "http://www.cswea.org/mobile_include/include_all_size_headers.php?cur_section=" . $Cur_Section . "&cur_sub_menu=" . $Cur_Sub_Menu . "&cur_page=" . $Cur_Page;
```

As well as:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mobile_include/include_all_size_headers.php?cur_section=" . $Cur_Section . "&cur_sub_menu=" . $Cur_Sub_Menu . "&cur_page=" . $Cur_Page;
```

But I get nothing.  No errors, and I have confirmed that the file is ok.

You can see this page at:
http://www.cswea.org/events/

Notice how it is just a plain shell.  No header html, and my AJAX call to fill the upcoming events isn't being called either?  the ajax file is in the same folder.

Includes on the home file are working, so I am lead to believe that this is a path issue.

What do I need to do to point to the file that is at cswea.org/mobile_include/include_all_size_headers.php?

any hints, clues or other help you can provide is greatly appreciated

EDIT:

I found this post:
[Include does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423702/include-does-nothing)

By switching to require (which was recommended in comments here as well) I got a fatal error.  By removed the ?=&='s, I was able to get it to include the file.
I now have the include working right, but the HTML isn't displaying correctly.  That is another issue that I think I can resolve on my own.

The solution was A) to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
And B) to eliminate the ?=&='s.

Comment: *"But I get nothing. No errors"* - [Is your server setup to catch and display them?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: instead of `include` use `require`

Comment: Good thought @Lashane.  Was failing silently?

Comment: as per your solution: [that link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423702/include-does-nothing) that you found, mentions nothing about `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. nor `eliminate the ?=&='s` and the fact about "require", is only said in comments and not in any given answer in there.

Comment: to OP:  @Lashane should be posting his comment and converting it to answer in order for this to be the actual solution. IMO anyway. Plus, you can always add to his answer, or post your own.

Comment: *"to eliminate the ?=&='s"* - Switching to a newer version of PHP, doesn't just break (an include). I'll bet that the variables and/or GET calls were failing you somewhere. Error reporting would have signaled that too. Sorry, but I just don't buy this.

Answer (score 0):

Is [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) enabled?  I believe it is off by default.

> This option allows the use of URL-aware fopen wrappers with the
>   following functions: include, include_once, require, require_once.

Requires `allow_url_fopen` also be on, which it should be by default.

As observed though you should get warnings/errors.

Comment: I found this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423702/include-does-nothing  Switching to require() gave me errors.  I removed the ?=&= 's and I now have it including the files, it still isn't outputting correctly, but it's a start.  I may not understand correctly, by wrapper you mean the ?=&='s ?

Comment: No.  wrapper as in "stream"... ie.  HTTP wrapper.  My answer would be all or nothing type thing.  On or off.  Sounds more like maybe an escaping issue with the URI you are building, or something server side to where you make the call.